# keepRunning set to false - what does it really do on Android?

Tags: android, cordova

I have an application that keeps an active WebSocket connection to a server as long as it is running and the server continuously pushes state updates to the client.

When the app is sent to the background, I want it to be halted (not shut down) and according to the Cordova Doc setting "**KeepRunning**" to "false" should do the trick. But I still see network traffic in monitor apps and logs of my websocket after the app was sent to the background, so it wasn't completely halted.

So I thought I simply kill the network connections right before the app goes to the background, but there's the issue: the **"pause"-Event** fires after the App was brought back to the foreground, right before the "resume"-Event fires.

How are you guys dealing with this? Does this work in your cases?

Comment: Seems there was similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519427/saving-socket-io-client-on-phonegap-resume-or-disconnecting-it-on-pause but no answer.
I think it is not good to keep alive TCP/IP connections, to save battery. AFAIK most communications are processed as HTTP requests in Android apps. I think it will be right for your case if you close and create new connection on app pause/resume. I have no experience in Cordova, I know how to do it in Android code only

Comment: Thank you for the link to the other question. I don't want to keep it alive! I want to close it, but with keepRunning set to false, I don't get the "pause"-Event until the app is reactivated, so I've got no chance to do so. I think there's a bug in Cordova/Phonegap, if the "pause" event isn't sent out in time, at least the network communication is to be stopped too while the app is in the background.

Comment: Why not upvote my comment then? Also I posted an answer to that question there, you may want to upvote there as well )) For you case -  do you use any Cordova plugin for WebSockets? If so, then that plugin could handle app pause event with regard of keepRunning flag, it depends on its implementation (except for the issue I mentioned in that post, when foreground activity is started by Cordova app itself). But I doubt it does so, most likely sockets remain active in paused state.

Comment: It is strange that your app doesn't receive the pause event, according to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225694/phonegap-cordova-pause-event-triggered-on-resume-for-android-can-not-turn-off it depends on **keepRunning** flag indeed, people were able to solve a similar issue

Comment: Sorry, a correction - I posted an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27013607/1028256

Comment: possible duplicate of [keepRunning PhoneGap/Cordova](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001439/keeprunning-phonegap-cordova)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that [WebSocket.java](https://github.com/remy/phonegap_test/blob/master/plugins/org.apache.cordova.plugin.websocket.WebSocket/src/android/WebSocket.java) doesn't handle **onPause** event from **PluginManager**, and it means that sockets are not closed regardless **keepRunning** config setting.

According to this post [Phonegap / Cordova pause event triggered on resume for android; can not turn off audio as a result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225694/phonegap-cordova-pause-event-triggered-on-resume-for-android-can-not-turn-off) you can set **keepRunning** to *true* to fix the issue with the pause event, and it doesn't affect current **WebSocket** functionality.

You may need to stop JS timers yourself then, in your code, if you use any.

You can find some relevant info about **keepRunning** usage in my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27013607/1028256)

Comment: I wasn't using a plugin for WebSocket since my App requires Android 4.4+ and WS is supported out of the box here. So what this leaves us with is: keepRunning only affects the timers in javascript, the plugins are not affected. If you set keepRunning to "false", it your apps javascript won't receive the "pause" event until you reopen the app. You can only fix it by setting keepRunning to true and to stop the timers yourself.